# Time testing a Dyalog Idiom on large array

Tags: performance, hash, apl, dyalog

For this first row found idiom `(w∘{(↓⍺)⍳↓⍵})` there seems no reduction in search time even though the first search would be hashing the array making later searches much faster?

```
      w← 100000000 3⍴'123'
      w←w,[1]'321'

      z← ⎕AI[3] ⋄ w∘{(↓⍺)⍳↓⍵}'321' ⋄ (⎕AI[3])-z
100000001
2892
      z← ⎕AI[3] ⋄ w∘{(↓⍺)⍳↓⍵}'321' ⋄ (⎕AI[3])-z
100000001
2883
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/Search%20Functions%20and%20Hash.htm):

> Notice that retaining the hash table pays off only on a second or subsequent application of the derived function. This usually occurs in one of two ways: either the derived function is named for later (and repeated) use, as in the first example below or it is applied repeatedly as the operand of a primitive or defined operator, as in the second example.

```
      w←100000000 3⍴'123'
      w←w,[1]'321'

      f←w∘{(↓⍺)⍳↓⍵}
      z←⎕AI[3] ⋄ f'321' ⋄ (⎕AI[3])-z
100000001
2782
      z←⎕AI[3] ⋄ f'321' ⋄ (⎕AI[3])-z
100000001
16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBOWP2iaYG4CBgvGj3i3qhkbG6lwg0XKdaMNYdWMjQ3UurjQQ/1HHjGqNR22TH/Xu0nzUuxnM2lrLVQWUe9Q31dEz2jhW4VF3i0IaWBOYqQGT0NStIlohAA)

```
      w←100000000 3⍴'123' 
      w←w,[1]'321' 

      w∘{(↓⍺)⍳↓⍵}{z←⎕AI[3] ⋄ ⎕←⍺⍺ ⍵ ⋄ ⎕←(⎕AI[3])-z}¨'321' '321'
100000001
2375
100000001
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBOWP2iaYG4CBgvGj3i3qhkbG6gpcIOFynWjDWHVjI0MgHyjQMaNa41Hb5Ee9uzQf9W4Gs7bWVlcBFT7qm@roGW0cq/Cou0UByAEJ9e4CIgWgEiRBDZhCTd2q2kMrIEaDSQA)

Comment: Nice payoff on very large arrays. Any other idioms for general purpose lookups that retain the hashed table or some other data structure?

Comment: @JoeKillian They are all listed in the documentation I linked.

Comment: The Try It Link is to Tio showing the same idiom for testing and I know of the main Idiom page here http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/Idiom%20Recognition/Idiom%20List.htm but I think there is a way to hash a table then apply perhaps commonly used functions on it.  This is what I meant. Hash a table and what other commonly used phrases are there that might time benefit.  There are probably quite a few but say just the top three.  Or is this the only idiom or commonly used phrase that makes great use of a hash table?

Comment: Oops, I know see the link you were talking about.

Comment: @JoeKillian It may also have your interest to [hash an array](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Operators/Hash%20Array.htm "Hash Array") independently of creating an ad hoc function.